# Apply python code to all csv files in a folder

Tags: python, csv

I have 3000 csv files for machine learning and I need to treat each of these files separately, but the code I will apply is the same.  File sizes and number of lines vary between 16 kb and 25 mb, and 60 lines and 330 thousand lines, respectively. Also, each csv file has 77 columns. I wrote only code inside the loop with the help of the previous post, but after applying the code, I cannot update within the same files. I just applied the code from previous post
and get error "No such file or directory: '101510EF'" (101510EF is my first csv file on my folder)

Loooking forward to your help. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Please add you code as text in a code block, not as a picture.

Comment: 'code' path = "C:/Users/kaanarik/Desktop/tez_deneme/ornel/B6859FF4.csv"
os.chdir(path)
all_files = glob.glob('*.csv')

for file in all_files:
   df = pd.read_csv(file)
df['new_column'] =  df['pserverno']+df['pserverno']
df['new_column2'] =  df['target_faction']+df['new_column']
df.to_csv(file)

Comment: [edit] your question, not just as a comment! Please take the [tour] if you haven't done so already and read [ask], to familiarize yourself with some insight on how to set up a good SO question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the line:
`file_name=os.path.splitext(...)`

Just this:

```py
path = "absolute/path/to/your/folder"
os.chdir(path)
all_files = glob.glob('*.csv')

for file in all_files:
   df = pd.read_csv(file)
   df["new_column"] = df["seq"] + df["log_id"]
   df.to_csv(file)
```

Comment: code worked but doesnt update..

Comment: you also need to change `df.to_csv(file)`  instead of `df.to_csv(file_name)`

Comment: I'm sorry but nope again same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide absolute path WITH extension to pd.read_csv and df.to_csv methods.
e.g. `c:/Users/kaanarik/Desktop/tez_deneme/ornel/101510EF.csv`

Comment: It's worked but doesn't update own csv file.

Comment: How does your code look like now?

Comment: import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

path = "c:/Users/kaanarik/Desktop/tez_deneme/ornel/101510EF.csv"
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv")) #make list of paths

for file in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    df['new_column'] =  df['pserverno']+ df['pserverno']
    df.to_csv(file_name)

Comment: code worked but doesn't change anything on files

Comment: Well, your csv is saved under101510EF at current location. You need to provide the same path to read_csv and to_csv methods. The best solution would be to use your var `file` instead of the path I have provided you, it was just an example